# deploy to Heroku from multiple computers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I have two computers and want to use only one for deployment.

I regularly do push to my private git repo on another computer and on the current computer I do both push to git repo and deploy to heroku.

If I made changes on another computer (such as adding new files) and push to git repo, then pull these into yet another computer then push back to git repo then push to heroku, would my changes on the first computer (the new file for example) deploy correctly to heroku?

Comment: Yes, that should deploy correctly to Heroku.